# What version of SP1 for SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server, servicepacks

What version of the SP1 for SQL Server 2008 do i use for my dev machine? Running Windows 7 x64, but running a x86 version of SQL Server?

SQLServer2008SP1-KB968369-x86-ENU.exe
or
SQLServer2008SP1-KB968369-x64-ENU.exe

Answer (score 1):

You need [SQLServer2008SP1-KB968369-x86-ENU.exe](http://download.microsoft.com/download/1/6/3/163A851B-D956-42E9-B426-F5C0EBE6B654/SQLServer2008SP1-KB968369-x86-ENU.exe), as it is the SQL Server install you are updating, not the OS.

Answer (score 0):

SQLServer2008SP1-KB968369-x86-ENU.exe

Answer (score 0):

Match the version of SQL Server that you originally installed: x86.